# Using one WGTS folder for multiple rigify rigs

Tags: rigging

I have a scene with multiple identical rigs and would like to use the same WGTS folder for all of them. Is there somewhere I can redirect the armatures to the same widget folder?
Thanks!

Comment: Blender has no notion of "WGTS folder". The way controller custom shapes are targeted is by the direct object's data path. You could in theory make a script for it, if you are sure all the WGTS objects are the same across all rigs (they could look the same but not have the same position/rotation/scale from their origins across all rigs). **However**, if you are generating rigs using Rigify, you can pinpoint an existing WGTS collection in the Rigify armature panel.

Comment: Ah, thanks, makes sense, so in theory if I import the same rig twice. The second time without the WGTS folder it's controllers could refer to the original ones imported?

Comment: OK seems copying the original in one file seems to work. It refers back to the original widgets. Thanks L!

Comment: That's wonderful! You could post it as an answer with details on how to do it so that it helps anyone with the same question in the future.

Comment: Here we are in the comments. To post an answer, you need to scroll down below where you should see a big blue button "Answer Your Question"

Comment: Okay got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, L The solution is to copy the rigs in the scene and they will refer back to the original widgets. I was importing them from a second scene separately. Unfortunately if there is a second rig type imported, it will not refer to the first rig's wgts objects without changing the link manually or with a script as you suggest. I have only 2 types of rigs which I am using (but copying them a lot) So I can settle for having just 2 WGTS folders...